Why must c be positive in the definition of equivalent norms
The definition of equivalent norms is as follows:
$$\exists c, C \in \mathbb{R^{+}}: \forall v \in V: c|v|' \le \|v \|' \le C|v|’ $$
Why can't $c$ be negative, the left part of the inequality would still be smaller $\|v \|'$ because of $|v|'$, even if $c$ were negative?

Likely because it would cause all norms to be equivalent to each other, which certainly is a boring/useless definition.

The thing with equivalent norms is that they generate the same topology. You need the constants to be positive because balls with negative radius don't make sense.

"the left part of the inequality would still be smaller ∥v∥′"  We don't want it to smaller unless the norms are equivalent.

It's not just that "If we change it, the definition would still hold when it needs to".  We also need "If we change it, the definition would still fail when it needs to".  Allowing $c$ to be negative will keep the left hand side smaller when its supposed to be smaller.  But it will also force the left hand side to be smaller when it's not supposed to be smaller.

If $c$ is negative then, because $|v|' \ge 0$ for all $v$, it follows that $c|v|' \le 0$. But then, because $\|v\|' \ge 0$ for all $v$, the inequality $c|v|' \le \|v\|'$ is just true for all $v$.
So with that negative value of $c$ your definition of equivalence would thus be logically equivalent to the following:
$$\exists C \in \mathbb R^+ : \forall v \in V, \,\, \|v\|' \le C |v|'
$$
I'm sure you can come up with examples that satisfy this statement but do not satisfy the standard definition of equivalence (with a positive value of $c$).

Equivalent norms should have the same convergent sequences (that is, define the same topology).
Without the second inequality you could have $|v|$ equivalent to $\|v\|$ but not $\|v\|$  equivalent to $|v|$. Hardly what you want for "equivalent".
